# java expressions with binary operators in xbase not working

Tags: xtext, xtend, xbase

I'm using xbase

```
grammar xolang.Xolang with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase
```

and an

```
XBlockExpression
```

where I expect to write my code

When write an expression like

```
val c = 1 + 1
```

Then I get the following error

```
The method +(int) is undefined
```

The same happens with Strings. In fact it happens with every binary operator: ==, < , >, ... Now I know that xbase supports operator overloading, maybe that has something to do with it? (Maybe I still have to define somewhere that you can add numbers?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem.

You need to add the xbase.lib jarfile (the right version of course) to the buildpath of the project that *uses* your DSL.

Answer (score 2):

If you wonder how you can easily add the xbase lib in Eclipse: Right Click on your Project that makes use of your DSL, select Build-Path->Add Libraries and choose XTend Library. The XTend Library includes the correct XBase Lib.